Why is Weston recommeding to run an almost empty .target file at system service?
Introduction
I'm trying to get Weston up an running at startup. So far, I have only success to open Weston with root user. I have followed this manual: https://wayland.pages.freedesktop.org/weston/toc/running-weston.html#running-weston-from-a-systemd-service
Method
What I have done is to create a file called /etc/systemd/user/weston.socket
And inside that file I have pasted
[Unit]
Description=Weston, a Wayland compositor
Documentation=man:weston(1) man:weston.ini(5)
Documentation=https://wayland.freedesktop.org/

[Socket]
ListenStream=%t/wayland-0

Then I have also created a file called /etc/systemd/user/weston.socket
[Unit]
Description=Weston, a Wayland compositor, as a user service
Documentation=man:weston(1) man:weston.ini(5)
Documentation=https://wayland.freedesktop.org/

# Activate using a systemd socket
Requires=weston.socket
After=weston.socket

# Since we are part of the graphical session, make sure we are started before
Before=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=notify
TimeoutStartSec=60
WatchdogSec=20
# Defaults to journal
#StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

# add a ~/.config/weston.ini and weston will pick-it up
ExecStart=/usr/bin/weston --modules=systemd-notify.so

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target

I have reloaded the systemd
systemctl --user daemon-reload

And started it. It only works at root user.
systemctl --user start weston

So to make it work on e.g tty7 I have created a system service called /etc/systemd/system/mysession.service. I have also created an user called user by using adduser user command.
[Unit]
Description=My graphical session

# Make sure we are started after logins are permitted.
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

# if you want you can make it part of the graphical session
#Before=graphical.target

# not necessary but just in case
#ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty7

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl --wait --user start mysession.target

# The user to run the session as. Pick one!
User=user
Group=user

# Set up a full user session for the user, required by Weston.
PAMName=login

# A virtual terminal is needed.
TTYPath=/dev/tty7
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes

# Fail to start if not controlling the tty.
StandardInput=tty-fail

# Defaults to journal, in case it doesn't adjust it accordingly
#StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

# Log this user with utmp, letting it show up with commands 'w' and 'who'.
UtmpIdentifier=tty7
UtmpMode=user

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target

Then I have created a file called /etc/systemd/user/mysession.target
[Unit]
Description=My session

BindsTo=mysession.target
Before=mysession.target

I starting my mysession system service. Nothing special happens.
systemctl start mysession

I'm checking if I have tty7 online. Yes I do!
loginctl

Then I starting weston
systemctl --user start weston

Questions:

I want weston to start up by the user in tty7. How can I do that?

Why do I need start the user service mysession.target? It's almost an empty file!? Nothing happens when I start mysession.target by calling the system service mysession.service.


